# Visual Studio 2022 CPU C# performance profiles yields only whole method timing and not per line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling

I have a pretty simple C# program, but when I try to find CPU bottleneck, the profiler only show me the CPU usage of the method, without showing me which part of the method consumed the most time. [image: The first line contains the method Total CPU, but there is no data about other lines]
The method iteself iterates over dictionary, adds data to dictionary, sorts arrays, so stuff happens there and I wish to know what line takes the most time.

I've seen before that the profiler can further give information about each line, so I wonder why it's not doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the actual execution time of each method, you can follow the steps below:

1. You can add a breakpoint to your target method first. For example, I want to know how long my two Add methods actually execute.

[image]

2. You can enter the next step through f10, and you can see the execution time of each method in the Events column of the diagnostic tool

[image]

Viewing the time spent on each line of code is still applicable to the above method

**Second update:**

If you want to know the execution time of the code in the iteration, you can directly use the code to try:

```
foreach(var ... in Data)
{
   Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
   watch. Start();

  //Your code

   watch.Stop();

   Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I wish to get statistics over thousands of iterations, as done in a CPU profiling session. The weird thing is that for the DotNet code it shows the statistics per line, and in my code it doesn't, seems like I have some sort of wrong settings

Comment: @user1595443 Hi, I updated the answer. If it is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was the debug symbol path. I had the symbol cache folder checked as part of the symbol file location list
[image]

Once I un-checked it, the profiler started showing me per-line CPU usage

Comment: You can mark it as an answer so it can help more people